# How to track objects scheduled for later deletion?

Tags: c++, qt

It's often recommended to use `deleteLater()` instead of normal `delete` in Qt. However, it leads to a problem of dangling objects: they are marked for deletion but still appear on children lists returned by Qt API. (Since this behaviour is seriously counterintuitive, my rapidly developing Qt quirks sense made me verify it. They do.) So, is there an idiomatic way to track such objects? I could, of course, use an ad-hoc solution like

```
class DeleteLaterable
{
public:
     void markForDeletion() { mMarked = true; }
     bool isMarked() const { return mMarked; }
private:
     bool mMarked = false;
};
```

and publicly inherit everything from it, but it opens a whole different can of virtual inheritance worms. Any better ideas?

Comment: Remove child, then `deleteLater()`.

Comment: Will it work if you just call setParent(nullptr) on scheduling of object's deletion?

Comment: Thanks, guys. Will go with picking it out of the relevant lists by hand, then.

Answer (score 3):

As of Qt 5.8, there are no way to track objects scheduled for deletion out of the box.

Calling `deleteLater()` just post an event (`QDeferredDeleteEvent`) to the target object. As there is no way to get the list of pending events you cannot know which object will receive a QDeferredDeleteEvent.

To achieve what you want there are several solutions:

1. Use a "DeleteLaterManager"
   A class with a "deleteObject(QObject *)" function that will call deletelater() and keep track of the object until deleted.
2. Reimplement QAbstractEventDispatcher and track events of type `QEvent::DeferredDelete`.
3. Use a custom event class of type `QEvent::DeferredDelete` and instead of calling `deleteLater()` call  `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`.

If you are only concerned with such object showing in child lists, you could simply remove their parent when calling deleteLater().

On a side note, why "this behaviour is seriously counterintuitive"? The documentation of `deleteLater()` simply states that the object will be scheduled for deletion, why would the parent/child relation be affected?

Comment: @ Benjamin T It's counterintuitive because it's not how it normally works. After you mark a file for deletion, for instance, OS API does not list it along with normal files anymore. The file itself may be deleted much later and after several system-level procedures - all but the final one reversible - but from the business logic standpoint file's lifetime ends when you set the "delete this thing" flag.

Comment: @sigil The object is not "marked" for deletion, it is "scheduled" for deletion. Calling "deleteLater" do not change an object it just tells you that at some point in the future it will self delete. Generally speaking you shouldn't assume an API will do more than documented: "deleteLater" is not "markAsDeleted" and nowhere in Qt documentation it says that "about to be deleted object are not listed".